# How to have Express routing work with Angular routing with HTML5 style URLs?

Tags: html, url, express, angularjs, url-routing

I would like to make an AngularJS app with HTML5-style URLs (i.e. with no `#` fragment in the URL). Thus in the routing controller module of my Angular app I've got something like the following:

```
angular.module('app').config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider',function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true)
...
}

$routeProvider
.when('/1/:param', /* do something */)
.when('/2/:param', /* do something else */)
.when('/3/:param', /* do something else again*/);
```

A number of working examples like [AngularFun](https://github.com/CaryLandholt/AngularFun) don't use HTML5 mode. For a request like `http://localhost:3005/#/1/foo`, it's clear that

- the `http://localhost:3005/` part is handled server-side `/` by Express. Express happily serves our Angular-enabled `index.html`
- the `/1/foo` route is handled client-side by Angular's router

Say our `server.coffee` looks, as standard, something like the below (we serve the static `dist` directory that contains our compiled, minified Angular sources:

```
express = require 'express'
routes = require './routes'
dir = "#{__dirname}/dist"            # sources live here
port = process.env.PORT ? process.argv.splice(2)[0] ? 3005
app = express()

app.configure -> 
    app.use express.logger 'dev'
    app.use express.bodyParser()
    app.use express.methodOverride()
    app.use express.errorHandler()
    app.use express.static dir       # serve the dist directory
    app.use app.router
    routes app, dir                  # extra custom routes
```

If we do use HTML5 mode, our URL `http://localhost:3005/#/1/foo` becomes `http://localhost:3005/1/foo` (no more hash `#`). This time, the entire URL is intercepted by Express, and it gets confused because we don't define routes other than `/`.

What we would really like to say is that the latter part of the URL (`/1/foo`) should be 'delegated' to Angular for handling. How can we say this?

Comment: I'm not an Express user but this question should relate to any Angular backend. If you simply instruct your Express to route everything to root (http://localhost:3005) you should get your Angular front-end opened, and from there Angular should pick up the relative path and figure out which client route to open. So, if user requests http://localhost:3005/1/foo your Express should serve the HTML as if it received a request to http://localhost:3005/. At that point, once your served HTML loads Angular, Angular should pick up the current location and figure out which client-side view/ctrl to open.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It appears that it does all work. I didn't do that work myself, however. I relied on this skeleton project:
https://github.com/thanh-nguyen/angular-express-seed-coffee

This allows you a certain degree of control over which paths are handled by the client and which by the server.